# How to check for specific application installed in machine or can we get list of installed application in gwt ?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

How to check for specific software installed in machine
for e.g. we can find out for Browser and OS using Window.Navigator in gwt.
similarly i want to find out for particular installed software in my machine.

for e.g.
After downloaded a file in browser, it should get open using an installed application.
Can we check whether the application which opens this file is installed or not. Otherwise if it is possible to get the list of installed applications in gwt code?

some code example would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser and OS detected via Window.Navigator are not fail proof. They only observe pattern in the way a browser does stuff and classify into OS and Browser groups.

Browser run Javascript ( i.e GWT Code ) do not have privilege to query OS regarding installed software or hardware details!!!!!

**There is no possible solution in GWT/Javascript for this.**